# Are questions identifying a belief and asking if any denomination or theologian believes it considered on topic?

Tags: discussion

There is a question currently On Hold asking about how Jesus was able to see Nathanael underneath the fig tree  before Philip called him. It seems that the author has a particular interest in bilocation and wants to know whether the theory that Jesus may have been in two places at once is one which has been held within Christianity.  (I may be wrong about her intention but that doesn't affect this question.)

Perhaps it could be  asked whether any prominent theologian has explored this explanation.

I can see problems with this because a) if no denomination or prominent theologian has ever taught this it will be impossible to prove, and b) we wouldn't want answers such as "my uncle thought that", depending of course whose niece or nephew you may be. On the other hand it could turn out this has been a held belief and somebody will provide an answer.

Is there a way to ask this that would be acceptable on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Purely speculative or curiosity based questions are really just a waste of everyone's time. Question askers should demonstrate that they have a reasonable expectation that some segment of Christianity believes something. They could do this by quoting a prominent Christian individual, by referencing what another religion alleges that Christians believe, or by trying to show that one group's doctrine leads to some belief through clear logic.

Answer (score 0):

### Pure Speculation

Questions of this nature do draw speculation, if they are left hanging in the wind.

I have seen this question. I also understand that as the question stands, it cannot be answered here.

As far as being a waste of time? I disagree. It most certainly would be, were it not for the provisional guidance of more experienced members.

The question has biblical basis. It can be answered. It simply needs help from the community.

It is easy to wave an onerous hand from the dais. It is dutiful and respectable to make every reasonable effort to help improve a question which is out of scope.